# Scheduling a sql script from oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-scripts

I have created a script to automate data extraction and saved in the 
location: C:\Users\Jeni\Desktop\Status.sql

And I call the script manually from Oracle Sql Developer by running the command

`@C:\Users\Jeni\Desktop\Status.sql` as a script

How can I automate the script to run daily from oracle sql developer

Comment: Were you able to find the answer for this? I would like do the same as well.

Comment: Connections/[Your db]/Scheduler/Schedules Create a schedule. Then Connections/[Your db]/Scheduler/Jobs create a job and link it to your schedule

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `status.sql` extracts your data to the database server, convert `status.sql` into a stored procedure and schedule it to run daily. [This thread on Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=automate-the-generation-of-sql-query-output-to-csv) is a great starting point.