# How to schedule a trigger which will run automatically in sql developer that clean up 30 days older data from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, automation, triggers, scheduler

I want to run a scheduler which runs a trigger such that it should automatically wipe out the data which is more than 30 days old. So we already have a trigger as below and we need something to schedule that trigger automatically once it reaches 30 days. And here the days should be configurable.

I have created the below trigger for this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sampleTrigger
    ON database1.dbo.table1
    FOR DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM database1.dbo.table1
    WHERE date < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
GO
```

And also here is something which went wrong with the above trigger because now I am getting the following error:

> ORA-04071 :missing BEFORE,AFTER or INSTEAD OF.

What is wrong with the above trigger and how can I make this automatic using a scheduler that will clean up 30 days older data from a table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling a sql script from oracle sql developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428759/scheduling-a-sql-script-from-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: Triggers cannot be scheduled, they are fired when some database event occurs. You need to use [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-7E744D62-13F6-40E9-91F0-1569E6C38BBC).

Comment: I would say if you really want to delete the data on monthly/daily basis, it would be **much** better to use appropriate partitioning (month/day) and truncate/drop partitions. No one would care to cleanup 1-100k rows, but on a large dataset `delete` will be very slow.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, a trigger is not an appropriate *tool* for that. Convert it to a stored procedure (using Oracle's syntax; I can't tell which database code you posted belongs to) and schedule a monthly job which will then run that procedure.

Also, note that deleting "30 days" back might cause problems because not all days have 30 days; perhaps you'd rather use "1 month".

Sample table:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM test
  3  ORDER BY datum DESC;

        ID DATUM
---------- ----------
         4 15.10.2022
         3 28.09.2022
         2 15.08.2022   --> should be deleted today (21st of October 2022)
         1 30.07.2022   --> should be deleted
```

A procedure which deletes rows older than one month; if you really need 30 days, modify `where` clause to `< trunc(sysdate) - 30`:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_del
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     DELETE FROM test
  5           WHERE datum < ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -1);
  6  END;
  7  /

Procedure created.
```

Let's schedule a job:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
  3        job_name         => 'p_delete_test',
  4        job_type         => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5        job_action       => 'BEGIN p_del; end;',
  6        start_date       =>
  7           TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('21.10.2022 03:00 Europe/Zagreb',
  8                            'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi TZR'),
  9        repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=MONTHLY; BYHOUR=3; BYMINUTE=0',
 10        enabled          => TRUE,
 11        comments         => 'Deleting rows older than 30 days');
 12  END;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Check the job info by querying `user_scheduler_jobs`, e.g.

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(last_start_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') last_start,
  2         TO_CHAR(next_run_date  , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') next_run_date
  3  FROM user_scheduler_jobs
  4  where job_name = 'P_DELETE_TEST';

LAST_START          NEXT_RUN_DATE
------------------- -------------------
                    21.11.2022 03:00:00
```

We won't wait until next month, so I'll run it manually:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     DBMS_SCHEDULER.run_job ('p_delete_test');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM test
  3  ORDER BY datum DESC;

        ID DATUM
---------- ----------
         4 15.10.2022
         3 28.09.2022
```

If you don't need the job any more, delete it:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     DBMS_SCHEDULER.drop_job ('P_DELETE_TEST');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: so i am using oracle database and as you suggested i will use store procedure and that SP will run based on the Scheduler right and yeah i will use one months , so is this is sufficient to create this automated task as i just want to wipe out all the data from the specific table once its reaches 30 days i mean here no manual intervention is required right to call the SP again and Job scheduler would do the task for us automatically

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are not meant for scheduling. Use DBMS_SCHEDULER for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [T-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) syntax (used by [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)) which will not work for Oracle.

If you are using an Oracle database then use the Oracle syntax for creating a trigger which is:

```
create trigger <trigername> [BEFORE/AFTER/INSTEAD OF]  [INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE] on <table_name>
```

Triggers in Oracle can be set up for INSERT, UPDATE , DELETE or on Database operations like LOGON, LOGOFF, etc.
Having said that, triggers will not help you here as others pointed out.

In your case, you need to truncate a table based on some column value, so the best option for you would be to setup a DBMS scheduler job to run a SQL script/[PL/SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) stored procedure and purge older data in your table.